# 'ApplicationException' could not be found

Tags: c#, throw

[Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3e1jm.png) of my code with the error and my references.
There is an error with the 'ApplicationException', and I just don't know how to resolve it.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace Sharepoint_2013_REST_API
{
   public class Program
   {
       public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Init
            string baseURL = "hello";
            string uriString = "world";

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient _Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            _Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
            HttpResponseMessage resp = _Client.GetAsync(uriString).Result;
            string respString = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("BAD");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error notification:

> Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ApplicationException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 25

Comment: Can you build the sln ?

Comment: Nope, 'build failed'

Comment: Depends on what framework you target, it is not available in .NETCore for example.  Starting with a Universal project template would be your oops.  ApplicationException was a design mistake, just use Exception instead.  And be sure you actually *meant* to use a Universal template, it doesn't look very universal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`ApplicationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ApplicationException) class isn't available in Portable Class Libraries and ASP.NET vNext projects, which I think your project is.

More importantly:

> You should derive custom exceptions from the `Exception` class rather than the `ApplicationException` class. You should not throw an `ApplicationException` exception in your code, and you should not catch an `ApplicationException` exception unless you intend to re-throw the original exception.

So use `Exception` when you throw an exception.

Comment: Oh wait sorry, yes. Thank you! I'll accept it. I'm just new to this so I didn't really know what to expect.

Comment: It's planned to support in .Net Stanadard 2.0+ https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4222